# How to import from one Google colab notebook to the other?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I wish to work on Colab to run a ResNet, but every time I try to import the notebook of the ResNet to my main notebook I get an error.
I've tried many ways.

First:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import os
GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH_AFTER_MYDRIVE = None
GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH = os.path.join('drive', 'My Drive', 'FinalsProject')
print(os.listdir(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH))
import sys
sys.path.append(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH)
```

I can clearly see that the notebook that I need is there and this notebook is at the same location.

But when I do import I get an error.

The file name is 'resnet01.ipynd'

1.
A simple:

```
import resnet01
```

returns the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resnet01'
```

2. 

The code:

```
!pip install python-ipynb
import import_ipynb
```

The error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-ipynb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-ipynb
```

3. 

The code:

```
!pip install ipynb
import ipynb.fs.full.resnet01 as models
```

The error message:

```
ImportError: Could not import drive/My Drive/FinalsProject/resnet01.ipynb for ipynb.fs.full.resnet01: incorrect version or language.
```

Is there any way to make it work?
Or should I do it in another way...?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.it-swarm-vi.com/vi/python/ipynb-nhap-tap-tin-ipynb-khac/1042793988/

```
!pip install import_ipynb
!pip install ipynb

import import_ipynb
import ipynb

from ipynb.fs.full.tim_folder import tim_folder
```